# regex comma seperated list

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression that will match a comma separated list of integers. I've tried many things, and they work, but they don't work well enough for what I need.

The expression must reject any trailing comma (ex. 1,2,), any double commas (ex 1,1,,23), and any non-numeric character (ex. 1,a,2,43,2).

There must also be no spaces between the numbers. The numbers themselves can be of any length.

An example of a string that should be matched is 1,2,3,4,5,9,234

I appreciate anybody who can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PmicQv/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `\d+` - matches 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a comma followed by 1+ digits
- `$` - asserts the end of the line